# Reversing a linked list recursively

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list

This appears to work. Are there any edge cases I am missing? What are your thoughts on the algorithm and implementation?

```
template <typename el>
void Linkedlist<el>::reverse() {
    Node<el> * oldHead = head;
    Node<el> * tailAfterReversal = recReverseList( head->getNextNode() );
    oldHead->setNextNode(NULL);
    tailAfterReversal->setNextNode(oldHead);
}

// Reverses part of a linked list starting from toRevesrPortionHead, returns the tail node
// after the reversal operation has been performed
template <typename el>
Node<el> * Linkedlist<el>::recReverseList( Node<el> * toReversePortionHead ) {
    if ( toReversePortionHead->getNextNode() == NULL ) {
        head = toReversePortionHead;
        return toReversePortionHead;
    }

    Node<el> * tailAfterReversal = recReverseList( toReversePortionHead->getNextNode() );
    tailAfterReversal->setNextNode(toReversePortionHead);
    toReversePortionHead->setNextNode(NULL);

    return toReversePortionHead;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Algorithm

1. Since its recursive and O(n), for large n you may get a stack overflow.
2. It will fail if the head is null (empty).
3. This part is redundant:

   `toReversePortionHead->setNextNode(NULL);`

Since in each stack call you change the next pointer of the next to the current. For example:

In the base case :

`(4) -> (5) -> (9) -> (10) -> nil`

First pop:

`(4) -> (5) -> (9) <- -> (10)`

Second pop:

`(4) -> (5) <- -> (9) <- (10)`

You will end up with:

`(4) <- -> (5) <- (9) <- (10)`

So you set the member next of the resulting node to null

`nil <- (4) <- (5) <- (9) <- (10)`

---

### Node

Your node is generic, you should make it a nested class. Also your get and set methods are too verbose and I would personally omit them.

---

### NULL:

If you are using C++11 you should be using nullptr. If you are curious why is a better alternative you could check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816385/what-are-the-advantages-of-using-nullptr

---

### Code :

I would change it to this:

```
template <typename el>
void Linkedlist<el>::reverse() {

    if(!empty())
       recReverseList(head)-> next = nullptr;
}

template <typename el>
Node * Linkedlist<el>::recReverseList( Node* node ) {

    if ( node->next == nullptr ) 
        return head = node;    

    return recReverseList( node->next )->next = node;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for all the inputs, very very insightful. TIL a new C++ shorthand!